# How to terminate a line of code in Python when sub-function errors

Tags: python, function, nested

So I have some code that is in its simple structure like the code below. Basically I have two functions. One function takes the other as an input. What I want to have happen is if the function1 fails and would error, that it "exits" out and skips over the function2(function1()) line and continues on without ending the entire process.

```
def function1():
     try:
          something = some_function()
          return something
     except:
          exit()

def function2(input):
     operate(input)


function2(function1())
```

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `exit`, have it return an expected output --

```
def function1():
     try:
          something = some_function()
          return something
     except Exception as e:
          print(f"Something went wrong: {e}")
          return False
```

Then you can act based on it's boolean condition --

```
def function2(input):
    if input:
        operate(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ending the entire process is exactly what `exit` does. You should just let the exception go uncaught, and execute `function2(function1())` in a `try` statement.

```
def function1():
    return some_function()

def function2(i):
    operate(i)

try:
    function2(function1())
except Exception:
    pass
```

If `function1` isn't a function you have control over, you can specifically catch `SystemExit` that `exit` raises, though I would do so in as small a block of code as possible.

```
try:
    x = function(1)
except SystemExit:
    pass
else:
    function2(x)
```